# Reading checkbox value in Table inside Panel inside Panel

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am having problem in finding my table created in design time with one row and two columns then added more rows and columns dynamically with label and checkboxes with unique IDs. Now when I want to save all checkbox values, I cannot find my table using ID assigned at design time. I got outer panel and from its id inside panel but when try to get the table which is the first and only control inside this panel I got null even .controls = 5 for this panel and none is of Table type, all literals.

```
<asp:FSPanel runat="server" ID="pnlDealership" IsPopup="true" PopupBehaviorID="mpeDealerShip"
                Style="display: none; z-index: 1000">                
            <asp:FSPanel runat="server" ID="pnlDatafeed">
            <table  id="tblDataFeed" border="1" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="tdpadding">
                <tr class="gridheader">
                    <td align="center" >
                        <asp:Label ID="lblMDDataFeedProvider" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td align="center" >
                        <asp:Label ID="lblMDActiveInActive" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            </asp:FSPanel>
</asp:FSPanel>
```

And reading using this c# code

```
String rMatch = "dfd_";
String rTblName = "tblDataFeed";
FSPanel pnl1 = (FSPanel)pnlDealership.FindControl("pnlDatafeed");
Table tbl = (Table)pnl1.FindControl(rTblName);
```

but tbl = null, I have no idea. The problem is that I have to add rows and columns and checkboxes at run time and then on save collect all check/uncheck values to the database.

Comment: Make the table runat=server

Comment: just like @P.Sethuraman said, your table does not have runnat at server properties, so it does not exists as server side control.

Comment: Thanks @P.Sethuraman this works now. :) but giving no check box items inside it. As I said  I added rows dynamically. So what should I do to keep those rows at postback? I lost all of them.

Comment: @qazifarhan you must create all dynamic controls on every postback